# Re-writing underscore _.uniq

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
//for a sorted array
var iterator = function(value) { return value === 1; };
var numbers = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4];

expect(_.uniq(numbers, true, iterator)).to.eql([1, 2]);
```

Quick question. I'm writing my own version of [`_.uniq` from the Underscore library](https://underscorejs.org/#uniq). I have one test case that I can't pass simply because I don't understand it. From the above test conditions; how could applying `_.uniq` produce `[1, 2]` as the end result? I don't see what it's trying to get me to implement here as that's not even unique in any sense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument is a function that transforms the values before `_.uniq` performs comparison.

So your initial array becomes `[true, false, false, false, false, false]`, and `_.uniq` identifies duplicates based on this transformed array.

Since there are only two unique values - true and false - only two elements are included in the end result.

Comment: Thank you. So the expected value `[1, 2]` is really not the values from the original array being iterated over but really just equal to what? To clarify, I guess what would the 1 and 2 represent in the expected array?

Comment: The values are picked from the original array, but their uniqueness is identified by the transformed array. Let's say you iterator function is `return value > 2`. The transformed array would be `[false, false, false, true, true, true]`. There are 2 unique elements in the transformed array, their indices are 0 and 3. Next we pick elements at these indices 0 and 3 from the original array. And the result is `[1, 3]`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ah gotcha, it is the value of the first instance of each unique element. Makes sense. Thanks @alexey!